# php artisan not returning anything

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-7, laravel-artisan

Today I came across a very weird situation I have never encountered before and couldn't really find a fix anywhere.

Whenever I type `php artisan` in my console, it doesn't return anything. Tried cloning the repo (which works fine on other machines here) multiple times and did a fresh `composer update`, `composer install` and set-up for the laravel project.

Found multiple cases like this on SO, and after running `find -L ./ -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 php -l | grep "Errors parsing".`

I got this log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare random_bytes() in ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_openssl.php on line 83
>   Errors parsing ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_openssl.php
>   PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare random_bytes() in ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_dev_urandom.php on line 148
>   Errors parsing ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_dev_urandom.php
>   xargs: php: exited with status 255; aborting
>   xargs: php: exited with status 255; aborting
>   PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare random_int() in ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_int.php on line 191
>   Errors parsing ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_int.php
>   PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare random_bytes() in ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_mcrypt.php on line 76
>   Errors parsing ./vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random_bytes_mcrypt.php

Hopefully you guys can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your problem is the same as people who has linting problem in PHP 7 in this link: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/115 .

It's strange because for me it's working fine, so I must assume you aren't on the latest Laravel version or your `composer.json` file isn't correct, because all of your package dependencies that need `paragonie/random_compat` will have to point to the latest `paragonie/random_compat` package which is `2.0.4` .

Check all of your Laravel default packages version number on `composer.json`, make sure it's requiring to the correct required version like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
}
```

Note: For the future reader, I believe you won't have to change the Laravel version one if you don't want to upgrade, but I believe you do have to change all of the rest package version to make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much. After checking my composer.json artisan was working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`random_bytes()` and `random_int()` are defined in PHP 7 so the error comes when they are redeclared in the [Paragonie](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) lib. If you are using PHP 7 in this Laravel project, you should remove Paragonie as a dependency.